# Why can't my Soundblaster G6 connect after hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, sound-blaster

I have just bought a Soundblaster G6 which I love. Under Windows it works flawlessly, but on both Ubuntu 22.03 and 22.10 it works when I plug it in, but when I wake my computer from hibernate, the G6 starts as expected and then loses power? At least the LEDs go out. After a couple seconds it restarts, is available for a couple of seconds and then loses power. Unplugging it for a couple of seconds does solve the issue, but I don't want to do that every time I start my PC.
Thanks for your time